How can I download multiple files in Ansible?
We can use the module get_url to download a file in Ansible, but now I want to download multiple files using a loop,
for example, I have a config.txt file which contains the file list (foo.conf, guide.txt, and test.jar) I need to download.
How can I set them into variables, so that I can use the variable in the loop?
 - name: Download files
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: http://example.com/path/foo.conf
    dest: /etc/foo.conf
    mode: '0440'
   loop: "{{ fileList }}"

How can I read the config.txt file and set the contents to variable fileList, like fileList=foo.conf,guide.txt,test.jar?
Appreciate your help.

Like in the minimal example
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    fileList: "foo.conf,guide.txt,test.jar"

  tasks:

    - name: Download files
      ansible.builtin.get_url:
        url: "http://example.com/path/{{ item }}"
        dest: "/etc/{{ item }}"
        mode: '0440'
      loop: "{{ fileList | split(',') }}"

shown here?
Q: "the fileList may contain 100 files, so ideally the file list will be defined in a separate file, parsing the file and set to variable fileList"
For an INI-style like file called config.txt with content of
fileList=foo.conf,guide.txt,test.jar

a minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    fileList: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.ini', 'fileList', type='properties', file='config.txt') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: fileList

    - name: Download files
      ansible.builtin.get_url:
        url: "http://example.com/path/{{ item }}"
        dest: "/etc/{{ item }}"
        mode: '0440'
      loop: "{{ fileList | split(',') }}"

will have the required behavior.

Thanks for your reply, the point is the fileList may contain 100 files, so ideally the file list will be defined in a separate file, parsing the file and set to variable fileList
